# How to plot distribution of 30 features in one plot and differentiating by label in python

Tags: python, matlab, comparison, distribution, pairwise

I am beginner in python trying to plot the distribution of the Breast Cancer Wisconsin (Diagnostic) Dataset from UCI machine learning respiratory.

My dataset looks like this

```
(Mean_Radius)  (Mean_Texture)   Mean_Perimeter)   (Mean_Area)    (Mean_Smoothness)   Diagnosis
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   (17.99)       (10.38)           (122.80)         (1001.0)        (0.11840)          M
   (12.99)       (11.38)           (125.80)         (1021.0)        (0.12540)          B
   (15.99)       (9.38)            (123.80)         (1000.0)        (0.21840)          M
   (12.09)       (12.38)           (135.80)         (900.0)         (0.32540)          B
```

I want to create something like the picture below (a distribution of all 30 features)
[image]

but with the both classes separated like this;

[image]

anyone knows how I can do this in python or matlab?

I tried this code but it is not giving me exactly what I want.

```
sns.pairplot(Data,vars=['Mean_Radius','Mean_Texture','Mean_Perimeter','Mean_Area','Mean_Smoothness','Mean_Compactness','Mean_Concavity','Mean_ConcavePts','Mean_Symmetry','Mean_FractalDim','SE_Radius','SE_Texture','SE_Perimeter','SE_Area','SE_Smoothness','SE_Compactness','SE_Concavity','SE_ConcavePts','SE_Symmetry','SE_FractalDim','Worst_Radius','Worst_Texture','Worst_Perimeter','Worst_Area','Worst_Smoothness','Worst_Compactness','Worst_Concavity','Worst_ConcavePts','Worst_Symmetry','Worst_FractalDim'], hue='Diagnosis')
```

Is there an alternative way I can make this plot for all 30 features that clearly shows both class?

Comment: It is always better to ask question adding some data and code so people know what you have tried  to solve the problem. Can you add some code and data so people can anwser faster?

Comment: @MartaG.I would do that shortly

Answer (score 3):

the given example shows how to plot histogram for various features

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(24,200))
try:
    for i, col in enumerate(Data.columns.to_list()):
        plt.subplot(10, 3, i + 1)
        plt.hist(Data[col], label=col,color='blue')
        plt.legend()
        plt.title(col)
        plt.tight_layout()
except Exception as e:
    print(col,e)
```